# Compass-and-straightedge geometric construction problem (see image)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

Given circle *c* with center A and a chord HI, and a point G within segment HI, construct circle *d* with center C such that the radical axis passes through G and point F lies on both *d*, line HI and line CA.

TL;DR Given the things in blue, construct the things in red.

Intuition tells me that there should be an unique solution given the level of constraint. I have also constructed one point J on the red circle.

A purely geometric construction and proof, not utilizing analytic geometry, would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
[image: Given the things in blue, construct the things in red.]

[image: Ditto, with point J.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you constructed point $J$, you can construct $F$ as the intersection of the line $HI$ and the line perpendicular to $AJ$ passing through $J$. This is because $AF$ is a diameter of $d$. The rest of the construction is easy and I leave it to you.